# ¿Es posible pasar parametros provenientes del html a alguna funcion que este contenida en el created() {... }?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy tratando de pasar un parametro a una funcion que estoy llamando en el created (){ ... }, dicho parámetro proviene de mi html. para esto estoy usando vuejs.

ejemplo:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({
   el: '#main',
   data: {
    user: {
     cedula: ''
    },
    evaluaciones: []
   },
   created() {
    this.getEvaluaciones(parametro);
   },
   methods: {
    getEvaluaciones(parametro) { 
     console.log(parametro);
    }
   }
  })
 </script>
```

Comment: Podrías explicar de mejor manera de dónde viene y como esta definido el parámetro que quieres obtener?, un ejemplo textual sería de ayuda.

Comment: Si es lo creo, si puedes. Por ejemplo puedes seleccionar el valor de un input y pasarlo como parametro a tu función en el created ya que este se efectua luego de que el dom este cargado. Ten encuenta que es recien se cargue el dom por lo que solo servirá para obtener el valor por defecto de un input o otras cosas que no tengan ver con o que no se generen con manipulación.

Comment: asi mismo @denifersantiagofernandez, logre obtener el valor desde el input tipo hidden por medio de un id que le coloque y en el created lo guarde en una variable, asi: var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula").value

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
new Vue({             
  el: '#main',             
  data: {                 
      user: {                     
         cedula: ''                 
      },                 
      evaluaciones: []             
   },             
   created() {
     let parametro = document.getElementById('IdInput').value;
     this.getEvaluaciones(parametro);             
   },             
   methods: {                 
     getEvaluaciones(parametro) {                         
        console.log(parametro);                 
      }             
   }         
})
</script>
```

Como vemos *created()* funciona como un método por lo que dentro podemos usar cualquier código javascript como declaración de variables y posteriormente utilizar estos valores. Teniendo en cuenta que esto se ejecuta *recién haya cargado el DOM* es obvio que si obtendremos un valor de un *input*  este valor seria el por defecto ya que no habría tiempo para capturar una manipulación por el usuario tan tempranamente se ha cargado la pagina.

> Cada instancia de Vue pasa por una serie de pasos de inicialización cuando se crea, por ejemplo, necesita configurar la observación de datos, compilar la plantilla, montar la instancia en el DOM y actualizar el DOM cuando cambian los datos. En el camino, también ejecuta **funciones** denominadas enganches del ciclo de vida, lo que brinda a los usuarios la oportunidad de agregar su propio código en etapas específicas.
>
> Por ejemplo, el gancho *created()* se puede usar para ejecutar código después de crear una instancia.

[vuejs.org Doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)